# Ошибка bad array new length

Tags: c++, ооп

выдает такую ошибку "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length' what():std::bad_array_new_length Aborted" Как ее можно исправить?

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int length;
    cin >> length;
    Array array(length);
    array.method();
}
```

calc.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;
Array::Array(int n){ // конструктор, ввод и вывод n - 1 пункт 
    length = n;
    cout << "N = " << length << endl;
}
void Array::method(){
    for (int i =0;i<length;i++){
        cin >> arr[i];// считывание элементов массива - 2 пункт 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        if (i<length-1) cout << arr[i] << " ";
        else cout << arr[i];
    }
        cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < length/2; i++){// разворот исходного массива - 4 пункт
        int temp = arr[i];// буфер
        arr[i]=arr[length-1-i];
        arr[length-1-i]=temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){// вывод перевернутого массива - 5 пункт
        if (i<length-1) cout << arr[i] << " ";
        else cout << arr[i];
    }
}
```

header.h

```
#define header_H
class Array{
    public:
    int length;
    Array(int n);
    void method();
    int *arr = new int[length];
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы выделяете память под массив **раньше**, чем задаёте длину. Всё потому, что атрибуты класса, проинициализированные сразу при объявлении, инициализируются до того, как выполняется тело конструктора. Пройдитесь отладчиком по шагам по своей программе, и Вы увидите, что, прежде чем сделать `length = n;`, программа перейдёт к строке `int *arr = new int[length];`, при этом, естественно, `length` ещё не будет иметь нужного Вам значения.

Чтобы исправить ситуацию, нужно перенести строку `int *arr = new int[length];` в конструктор, а в объявлении атрибутов класса оставить просто `int *arr`. Таким образом, конструктор примет вид:

```cpp
Array::Array(int n){ // конструктор, ввод и вывод n - 1 пункт 
    length = n;  // Сначала узнаём длину
    arr = new int[length];  // Потом выделяем память под массив нужной длины
    cout << "N = " << length << endl;
}
```

А там, где у Вас было

```cpp
int *arr = new int[length];
```

должно остаться просто

```cpp
int *arr;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработала